# converting array to different types (lodash/js)

Tags: javascript, arrays, type-conversion, lodash

What would be the most straightforward way to convert the type of each element in an array on a one-by-one basis?

For example, if I have:

```
var a = ["2013", "72", "68", "76", "75", "76", "73"]
```

how could I transform `a` to the following, keeping the first item a string and converting the rest to integers:

```
["2013", 72, 68, 76, 75, 76, 73]
```

In lodash, I can manage `_.map(_.values(record), _.toNumber)` converting the entire array to numbers, but how would I map to each item in the array?

Comment: What is the rule by which you want to keep 2013 as a string but convert the others to numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) with the index of the loop.

```js
var a = ["2013", "72", "68", "76", "75", "76", "73"];
  
a = a.map(function (b, i) {
    return i ? Number(b) : b;
});

console.log(a);
```

Comment: @Yosvel Quintero No the `a` variable declaration should end with a comma and so it does.

Comment: @Redu, i changed the comma. it was leftover.

Answer (score 2):

Using lodash methods [map](https://lodash.com/docs#map), [toNumber](https://lodash.com/docs#toNumber) and checking not the first in array:

```js
var a = ["2013", "72", "68", "76", "75", "76", "73"];
var result = _.map(a, function(v) {
    return a[0] !== v ? _.toNumber(v) : v;
});
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.12.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe :

```js
var a = ["2013", "72", "68", "76", "75", "76", "73"]
var newArray = [];
a.map(function(d, i) {
  if (i == 0) {
    newArray.push(d)
  } else {
    newArray.push(parseInt(d, 10))
  }
  return newArray

})
console.log(newArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var a = ["2013", "72", "68", "76", "75", "76", "73"]
var b = a.map(function(item) {
  if (item.length === 4) {
    return item;
  } else {
    return parseInt(item, 10);
  }
});
console.log(b)
```